# is there any way we can connect powerBI through automation script(python)

Tags: python-3.x, azure, automation, powerbi

I am trying to find a way to connect powerBI, but coudn't found any resources to do same. e.g we can connect to mssql,postgress etc

thanks.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you want to achieve? Thanks!

Comment: @kgalic i trying to automate the task of creating dashboard on powerBi, for that i want  to connect powerBi from script.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Python scripts directly within Power BI and this allows access to the data sets as inputs and outputs back in to the data model.

[Here is a link to the official documentation for the feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-python-scripts)

You can also use the Python visual. This doesn't allow you to feed in to the data model but instead uses it to generate a visualisation which is then directly displayed.

[Documentation on the Python visualisation is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-python-visuals)

Comment: thanks for posting but i am looking for different thing, I want to connect to Power BI through my local simple script. is there any way we can do?

Comment: What do you mean by Power BI? Desktop, cloud, Power Pivot?

Comment: its a cloud. btw i got the power BI API documentation.                                                  [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/) this will work